# IDE that can refactor CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ide

I have an index.html file in directory XXX and other html files in various subdirs.

In XXX, I have also the usual dirs js, images, and css that contain the corresponding files.

Is there an IDE that would allow me to somewhat automatically refactor id and class names throughout the whole project, and also check whether files contained in the dirs js and css, and images in the images dir, and so on, are being used?

Comment: Try Intel XDK or Atom

Comment: **Any** decent IDE would do that for you. I use Dreamweaver for example. However, asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, tutorials or other off-site resources are are considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)'.

Comment: Where should I ask, then, if it off-topic!

Comment: And, if somebody cares to answer, the USE should alsobe able to flag the css tags that are bout being used...

Comment: Quora is a good place to ask this type of question. Unfortunately, on SO, we mainly answer questions that have aren't opinion-based (which this question definitely is, as it asks for a recommendation as opposed to a direct answer).

Comment: My question ous not about opinions at all!

Comment: It is very concrete:  Is there an ide that CAN do what I ask?